# is it possible to run one specific seleniumtest on many urls?

Tags: selenium-ide

i have recorded a list of all the webpages i need to test (>400).
now i would like to tell selenium-ide to do a verification on all these pages.

```
### example: what i usually do: ###

 1. open /test/page1
 2. VerifyTextNotPresent "ERROR"
 3. open /test/page2
 4. VerifyTextNotPresent "ERROR"
 5. open /test/page3
 6. VerifyTextNotPresent "ERROR"
 7. ...
```

as you notice, the test itself (identifying the "ERROR") has to be written 400 times for the 400 pages that have to be tested. 
i will end up with 400 lines saying "VerifyTextNotPresent "ERROR"" + 400 lines opening the webpages = 800 lines in selenium-ide.

```
### example: what i would like to do: ###

 1. VerifyTextNotPresent "ERROR" FOR all these ... 
 2. open /test/page1
 3. open /test/page2
 4. open /test/page3
 5. ...
```

if this would be possible, i would end up with 401 lines instead of 800 and in case of a change, lets say another test (AssertText "ABC") it would only need little work to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here are some usefull answers for using javascript capability (such as "while") in selenium.

[=> "onlineseleniumtraining.com](http://onlineseleniumtraining.com/sequence-of-evaluation-and-flow-control-while-loop-in-selenium-ide/)

[=> stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14955000/selenium-ide-loop-through-array-variables)

special thanks to karina!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use looping and parametrization..where for each iteration you can pass new webpage URL and will check whether ERROR is there or not.

```
open |  pass URL (parametrization)
while loop
then you can check with 
if ERROR text present 
Do this
Else
Do this
endWhile
```

With this there is no need to write that command again again..you can run this loop 400 times with new URL every time.
let me know if there is any doubt.

Comment: i am using selenium-ide-plugin for ff.

there are 3 fields i can use, command; target; value 

i don`t understand how i can use certain code (like example above) in this ide since there are no such commands available when opening the list of commands.